# Create gradient image programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to process some imagedata which comes directly from the device camera. In order to understand the CGImage structure, I'm using a buffer to create an image which doesn't work right for me (I know that I shouldn't use C code within Obj-C Code, it's just for understanding). The code is as follows:

```
int *outBuf = malloc(sizeof(int) * width * height);
for (int i = 0; i < width * height;i ++)
{
     outBuf[i] = (((float)i) / ((float) width * height)) * 255.f;
}
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(outBuf, width, height, 8, width * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
CFRelease(ref);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
free(outBuf);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

[view.imgView setImage: [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img]];

CGImageRelease(img);
```

This should create a gradient from the very first to the very last pixel, but it results in a weird graphic:

[image: generated image]

Where do the horizontal spacings come from? (I want to solve this issue, I'm aware that there are other possibilities to draw the gradient) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution:

I was initialising the buffer with int*. Every int is 4 bytes long, but a grayscale picture just needs 1 byte per pixel. Changing the buffer to char* and modifying the CGBitmapContextCreate parameters fixed the issue:

```
CGBitmapContextCreate(outBuf, width, height, 8, width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches to implementing what you wish. Here's two examples:
Please note that this is just to show you an example, you should addapt parameters/colors/etc to get exactly what you're after. Hope this helps.

1) Drawing gradient directly in draw rect. If you wish additional drawing, also call [super drawRect:rect] in your view implementation.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(self.centerOffset, CGSizeZero) == NO) {
        center.x += self.centerOffset.width;
        center.y += self.centerOffset.height;
    }

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    size_t num_locations = 2;
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGFloat components[8] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5,   // Start color
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7 }; // End color

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);
    CGGradientDrawingOptions options = kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation;
    CGFloat endRadius = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds.size.height / 2;
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(currentContext, gradient, center, 50.0f, center, endRadius, options);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace); 
}
```

2) Use CAGradient Layer

```
    UIColor *startEndColour = [UIColor redColor];
    UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    NSArray *horizontalGradientColorsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startEndColour CGColor], (id)[middleColor CGColor],(id)[middleColor CGColor], (id)[startEndColour CGColor],nil];

    UIView *horizontalGradient1View = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.bounds.size.width, 1.f)];
    horizontalGradient1View.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    CAGradientLayer *horizontalGradient1 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    horizontalGradient1.frame = horizontalGradient1View.bounds;
    horizontalGradient1.colors = horizontalGradientColorsArray;
    horizontalGradient1.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
    horizontalGradient1.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
    [horizontalGradient1View.layer insertSublayer:horizontalGradient1 atIndex:0];
    [self addSubview:horizontalGradient1View];
    [horizontalGradient1View release];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of those possibilities, but basically I'm trying to understand why the codelisting isn't working (I need the mentioned buffer for the CIImage)