# Add blur mask on top and bottom of the screen in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, gradient, mask

I need to add mask on top and buttom of the screen like this.

How can I achieve this ? [image]

Comment: I guess you should check this link out : [UIVisualEffectView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067719/how-to-use-uivisualeffectview)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {        
        self.BlurView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
        UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [blurEffectView setAlpha:1.0];
        [self.BlurView addSubview:blurEffectView];        
    }
```

Where  `self.BlurView` is type of `UIView` .

You can keep this for your upper and bottom view . And can adjust frame `blurEffectView.frame` according to your upper and bottom dimensions .

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up UIImageView with your background image.
2. Add UIVisualEffectView over the top:

   ```
   UIVisualEffectView * vs = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]];
   vs.frame = self.view.bounds;
   [self.view addSubview:vs];
   ```
3. Add a UIView over the top, and put your UITableView (or whatever) in that.
4. Add this code:

   ```
   CAGradientLayer * layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
   layer.frame = tableHolder.bounds;
   layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, nil];
   layer.locations = @[@0.90,@0.99,@1.0];
   layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0f);
   layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
   tableHolder.layer.mask = layer;
   tableHolder.layer.masksToBounds = true;
   [tableHolder.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
   ```

Adjust the variables for your own needs, you'll have to change the locations.

You're not 'blurring' the tops and bottoms, but gradually masking them out via the gradient layer.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a way to achieve this effect. But what you need is not a blur mask, you need to use a clipping mask.

1- present a modal view controller with a view that contains a UIVisualEffectView in the back, and a scrollview/tableview/collection view in the front that is offset 40px (or however much you want) from the top and bottom. 
2- Add a mask to the scroll view using a black and white image tailored to the task, you can add the mask using the following code:

```
var maskImage = UIImage(name: "yourMask")
var maskLayer = CALayer()
maskLayer.frame = scrollView.bounds()
maskLayer.contents = maskImage.CGImage
scrollview.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

3- Alternatively, you can also use CAGradientLayer to achieve the same effect (this would work better with scaling as well). There's plenty of solutions on stack overflow on how to create a gradient layer, like this one: [Create gradient image programmatically in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625763/create-gradient-image-programmatically-in-ios)

Having said that I don't understand why your question is down voted. I think it's a perfectly good question to make.

Hope this helps!